# Connection aborted while Uploading files

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, filesize

I have an angularjs file upload method that includes a basic php
   server side script
My problem  is when i upload an icon evrything works fine else i got
   connexion aborted, note that in PHP.ini by defaut i can  upload file
   max size 2M, it seems like  i can't upload file max than 10 kb  . any
   suggestion ? Thank you
the problem is here(service.js) :

```
 .factory('UploadService', function ($http, $ionicLoading, Upload) {
        return {
            uploadFile: function (_photo, _formID, callback) {
                $ionicLoading.show();
                Upload.upload({
                    url: php/ws_upload_file.php,
                    headers: {
   'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   // or  'Content-Type':'application/json'
 },


       data: {photo: _photo, 'user_id': _formID}

                }).then(function (resp) {
                    callback(resp.data);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, function (resp) {
                    callback(resp.data);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, function (evt) {

                });
            }
        }
    })
```

the problem is with the data photo , i can't send a file as an object when it's bigger than 10kb

Comment: You are uploading image file using application/x-www-form-urlencoded use multipart file upload to upload files

Comment: i did that , but the same error keep showing. i'm stack with this problem for days, i can't figure out what causes the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/
Also check if you are able to upload file using just html so that you dont have any server side error

Comment: my code works perfectly when i tried with other machine , also it used to work fine for me , there's also a solution that worked for me , is when i tried to add the hostname before the url exp (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81/php/ws_upload_file.php)

Comment: Did you try set_time_limit(0)

Comment: in php.ini i found max_execution_time = 30 ? do i have to make it 0 ? no limit ?